# php writing isset check in if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, isset

Very stupid question how to check 2 things in 1 if. , I'm getting errors typing code in a wrong way.

I need to check if expression A isset, OR expression B isset in 1 IF statement

My code is `if (isset(expression1) OR isset(expression2)) {}`

this is an yii framework this is fullcode

```
if (isset(Yii::app()->user->viewUsersPage) OR isset(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('guest')))
```

something is wrong there...

Comment: Why are you `isset` ing an expression ??

Comment: Actually your script is correct, though use `||` instead of `OR`

Comment: actuaaly it's not an expression but a call to some variable. sorry

Comment: @crypticous you can use `OR` just fine.

Comment: Could you show a part of your expressions ?

Comment: @Styphon I know, though it isn't recommended

Comment: @David Can you please update your question with your actual code? What are the exact errors that you are getting?

Comment: If the expressions are variables there is no reason for errors. what errors do you get?

Comment: @crypticous Why not? There are certain frameworks (Kohana for one off the top of my head) that use it all the way through. It's perfectly fine and there's no recommendation either way.

Comment: updated with full code

Comment: @David and the errors?

Comment: white screen. some grammar error probably

Comment: @Styphon I meant that `||` is commonly used, not `OR`. That's why I am considering that it isn't recommended, though it is working just fine in both cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's this?  Checking `isset` on a function return?

```
isset(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('guest'))
```

Maybe you want to check for `true`:

```
if (isset(Yii::app()->user->viewUsersPage) || Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('guest'))
```

Or:

```
if (isset(Yii::app()->user->viewUsersPage) || (Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('guest') == true))
```

I don't know the code, but maybe you should be checking for `true` on `viewUsersPage` as well?

Maybe also try this instead of `isset(Yii::app()->user->viewUsersPage`:

```
if (property_exists(Yii::app()->user, 'viewUsersPage') || Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('guest'))
```

Though `isset` should work fine.

Comment: this code works, but the problem is that now I'm getting messages that WebUser.viewUsersPage is not defined. And I understand why it is. And that's why I was trying to bypass it with isset.
I mean the WebUser.viewUsersPage maybe present and just check it, and may not present.

Comment: AbraCadaver second part of IF is OK. Problem is with first part, which sometimes exist in my application and sometimes no. And because of that I'm checking it here in the way to bypass it without errors if it is not present. That's why I write isset, but I still getting errors :(

Comment: Edited, try `property_exists()`

Comment: HEY sorry , was my fault! This code works just fine!

Comment: property_exists not needed. isset works fine, had some other errors, in line after this. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

We use the || operator. See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

```
if (isset(Yii::app()->user->viewUsersPage) || isset(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('guest'))) {

   // do something
}
```

Comment: Wow... the page you even link uses `OR` as well as `||` in the first example.

Comment: `||` has a greater precedence than `OR`